# I want to return Count of a Collection in addition to the other elements of a table in the database

Tags: asp.net-web-api, controller

I want to also return in addition to the parameters of the Buyers Class I want to return the number of properties owned by the buyer using a GET method in the controller.

How can I change the GET function to select the fullName, Credit and Number of Apartments owned:

```
public class Buyer
{
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }
public string FullName { get; set; }
public int Credit { get; set; }
public ICollection<Apartment> apartments { get; set; }
} 

// GET: api/Buyers
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Buyer> GetBuyers()
{
return _context.Buyers
.Include(a => a.apartments);
}
```

Comment: Could you please what is your `_context.Buyers`? and what is it returning?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/139c6649-98ff-49a4-a835-f7cea7f5070c/entity-sql-to-retrieve-record-and-count-of-related-records?forum=adodotnetentityframework